# Google Places and Autocomplete, problem updating to the New Places SDK

Tags: google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

The Google Play Services Places SDK is deprecated so I'm in the process of updating. I've already updated to `Androidx`.

I've migrated to the New Places SDK Client as per [this](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration) guide, changing `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.4'` in my `build.gradle` file to `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'`

And in my `Activity` I've changed:

`import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;` to

```
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
```

So, that problem has been rectified, it no longer comes up as a red error.

But I am still getting:

[image]

Do you know how I can solve this? I've tried preceeding each red text with `com.google.android.libraries.places.api` to no avail.

The possible solutions I looked up on SO are old and don't deal with this Places migration which only happened in July 2019.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you initialized the new Places SDK client? i.e. `Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), apiKey);` and `PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);`?

Comment: Also can you please post your code?

Comment: @evan Yes, it is initialized. I'm trying some new things, maybe my Places Adapter file is not necessary with the move to the new Places dependency. Will report back with developments.

Comment: Right! Please keep us posted. :)

Comment: Turns out in fact the new places library is completely different to the old one in gms.location...had to rewrite the whole thing, wasn't a matter and using old methods . I found this video useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtOYctzpa_w. The code is much more simple and streamlined than it had been before.

Comment: Thanks for your update and for sharing that vid. I suggest you answer your own question and then accept it for the community's sake.